# Slider in li using jquery

Tags: jquery, uislider

This code is working for next prev but not gives smooth sliding effect. Please help to make it smooth. 
I have variours list data which need to be shown in slider effect with next prev button.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#prev').hide();

var $lis = $("#myList li").hide();
$lis.slice(0, 10).show();
var size_li = $lis.length;
var x = 10,
start = 0;
if(size_li == x)
{
    $('#prev').hide();
    $('#next').hide();
}
$('#next').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#prev').show();
    if (start + x < size_li) {          
        $lis.slice(start, start + x).hide();
        start += 1;
        $lis.slice(start, start + x).show();   
    }
    if(start + x == size_li)
    {
        $('#next').hide();
    }       
});
$('#prev').click(function () {
    $('#next').show();
    if (start >= 1) {
        $lis.slice(start, start + x).hide();
        start -= 1;
        $lis.slice(start, start + x).show();
    }

    if(start == 0)
    {
        $('#prev').hide();
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer with least code is to add `'slow'` attribute to `hide()` and `show()`.
So instead of `hide()` do `hide('slow')` and instead of `show()` do `show('slow')`.

You can also apply css to all elements which are shown/hidden, like this

```
.elm {
    transition: all lienar 500ms;
    -webkit-transition: all lienar 500ms;
    -moz-transition: all lienar 500ms;
}
```

In this case `'slow'` property will not be required.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Slow attribute not working to give sliding effect.

Comment: also I have applied given css to all li element but no any changes occurred.